# I am looking for statistics on the percentage of children's books versus other genres in self-publishing

Tags: data-request, publishing

I have tried doing searches for this and can't seem to track down the exact numbers. The sources will list the top selling genres but that doesn't include children's books. I am giving a presentation in October 2017 and need this information.